# ERRO "ROOT ELEMENT IS MISSING" AO TENTAR DESSERIALIZAR XML EM XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: c#, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

```
    public T Exportar<T>(T obj, string nomeArquivo)
    {
        try
        {
            string file = Global.LocalPasta + nomeArquivo + ".xml";
            if (File.Exists(file))
                File.Delete(file);
            using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializador = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializador.Serialize(stream, obj);
            }

            return obj;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public T Importar<T>(string nomeArquivo, bool lista = false)
    {
        try
        {
            string file = Global.LocalPasta + nomeArquivo + ".xml";

            XmlSerializer desserializador = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            T obj;
            using (Stream reader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                obj = (T)desserializador.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

---

aí está o xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfUsuario xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Usuario>
    <dataHora>2019-06-03T17:42:00.776232-03:00</dataHora>
    <excluido>false</excluido>
    <idUsuarioGravou>1</idUsuarioGravou>
    <idUsuario>0</idUsuario>
    <cpf>11111111111</cpf>
    <senha>123</senha>
  </Usuario>
  <Usuario>
    <dataHora>2019-06-03T17:42:00.907262-03:00</dataHora>
    <excluido>false</excluido>
    <idUsuarioGravou>1</idUsuarioGravou>
    <idUsuario>0</idUsuario>
    <cpf>11111111111</cpf>
    <senha>123</senha>
  </Usuario>
  <Usuario>
    <dataHora>2019-06-03T17:42:00.907382-03:00</dataHora>
    <excluido>false</excluido>
    <idUsuarioGravou>1</idUsuarioGravou>
    <idUsuario>0</idUsuario>
    <cpf>11111111111</cpf>
    <senha>123</senha>
  </Usuario>
</ArrayOfUsuario>
```

Aqui está a chamada do método

```
var X = new DTO().Importar<List<Usuario>>("Usuarios");
```

Comment: E onde está o xml? A descrição do erro parece ser bem clara

Comment: Dá um erro de exceção com a mensagem "root element is missing" na função importar

Comment: respondi com o código do xml

Comment: O método importar está funcionando, desde que a classe usuário tenha suas propriedades declaradas com a primeira letra minúscula, assim como apresentado no XML. Você verificou se `Global.LocalPasta` está apontando para local correto?

Comment: O problema foi resolvido?

Comment: o problema foi resolvido